# How do I view the initial set of commits on a github.com repo without paging through hundreds of pages of commits?

Tags: github

I don't want to clone the repo locally and search through it. I am just trying to get the date of the first couple commits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty easy if you modify the URL when browsing through the history.

**Instructions:**

1. On the landing page of the repo, find the number of commits.

*For example, the [googlesamples/unity-jar-resolver](https://github.com/googlesamples/unity-jar-resolver) repo almost **500 commits** as of today.*

2. Click on the **commits** tab, scroll down, and click on the **Older** button at the bottom of the page.

*URL should look like this:*

```
https://github.com/googlesamples/unity-jar-resolver/commits/master?after=e703601cec96ff60883b8999ca9aaa3ef2e459d9+34
```

You want to modify the number at the end of the URL **(+34)**.

`master?after=e703601cec96ff60883b8999ca9aaa3ef2e459d9+34`

3. Change **34** (or whatever number you see) to the total commits minus about 50. In my case, that would be **450** (500-50).

Should now look like this:

```
https://github.com/googlesamples/unity-jar-resolver/commits/master?after=e703601cec96ff60883b8999ca9aaa3ef2e459d9+450
```

4. Load that URL and you should see your initial set of commits.

Comment: You think that GitHub would've thought of this already and made it a feature lol. Thanks for the solution!